# ¿Como puedo agregar varios inputs en una tabla para agregarlos a la base de datos? Laravel 5.7

Tags: html, css, laravel

La situacion es la siguiente, en un formulario tengo una tabla que tiene los siguientes campos

```html
<div class="tablaAgregar">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Detalle del Bien/Servicio</th>
    <th scope="col">Unidad de Medida</th>
    <th scope="col">Cantidad Requerida</th>
   </tr>
   <td scope="row">
    <div class="columna1">
      <input id="detalle" placeHolder="Ingrese Detalle del Bien/Servicio....." name="detalle" type="textField" class="form-control input-md" required>
   </div>
         </td>
   <td>
    <div class="columna2">
                          <input id="unidadMedida" placeHolder="Unidad" name="unidadMedida" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div class="columna3">
     <input id="cantidad" placeHolder="Cantidad" name="cantidad" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required>
    </div>
   </td>
  </thead>
 </table>
```

La pregunta seria, como hago para agregar mas inputs (se requieren unos 10 dentro de la misma tabla) y que se agreguen a la base de datos. Ya que intente ponerlos en el formulario directamente, pero se guarda solo el primero.

Aqui esta el controlador que guarda en la base de datos.

```
    //Funcion que agrega a la base de datos la informacion ingresada para la solicitud de compra. //
public function agregarSolicitud(Request $request)
{
    $solicitud = new App\SolicitudDeVentas;
        $solicitud->UnidadSolicitante = $request->unidad;
        $solicitud->NombreBienServicio = $request->nombre;
        $solicitud->DetalleBienServicio = $request->detalle;
        $solicitud->UnidadDeMedida = $request->unidadMedida;
        $solicitud->CantidadRequerida = $request->cantidad;
        $solicitud->JustificacionBienServicio = $request->justificacion;
        $solicitud->Observaciones = $request->observaciones;
        $solicitud->fechaAproximada = $request->fechaAprox;
        $solicitud->Enlace = $request->enlace;
        $idUser = \Auth::user()->id;
        $solicitud->User()->associate($idUser);
        $solicitud->save();
    Alert::success('Éxito', 'Solicitud agregada correctamente');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**EDIT**

Con la solucion de Shaz me arroja el siguiente error. Existe algun tipo de dato para la base de datos que me deje guardar arreglos?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumo que te refieres a más campos con el mismo nombre, para lo cual creas un array de estos:

```
<input id="detalle" name="detalle[]" />
```

En el controlador simplemente los lees como cualquier otro dato:

```
$request->detalle;
```

Si necesitas acceder uno a uno, utilizas un foreach:

```
foreach ($request->detalle as $detalle) {

    echo $detalle;

}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Shaz. Lo intentare y te aviso si me dio resultado :)